# R: Create matrix from character vector and remain NA in matrix

Tags: r, matrix, vector, na

I want to create a matrix from character vector similar to:

```
comments <- c("abc", "lol")
comm_matrix <- matrix(data=comments, ncol=3, nrow=1)
```

I want to get matrix, but with NA if ncol > nchar in vector:

```
[,1] [,2] [,3]
abc  lol  NA
```

Instead of default:

```
[,1] [,2] [,3]
abc  lol  abc
```

Comment: If you follow [Rich Scriven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29957940/8583393) in the linked post it will give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Thank's mates,
the solution is:

```
comments <- c("abc", "lol")
length(comments) <-prod(dim(matrix(comments, ncol=3)))
comm_matrix <- matrix(data=comments, ncol=3, nrow=1, byrow=TRUE)
comm_matrix

#    [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
#[1,] "abc" "lol" NA
```